# (Conversion from kilograms to pounds) Write a program that displays the follow-ing table (note that 1 kilogram is 2.2 pounds):

Tags: python, function, printing, format

can any one explain me print line.

```py
print("Kilograms  pounds")
for i in range(1,200,2):
  print('{:<9d} {:6.1f}'.format(i,i*2.2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Kilograms pounds")
for i in range(1,200,2):
    print('{:<9d} {:6.1f}'.format(i, i*2.2))
```

1) print("Kilogram pounds") - Is a basic print statement to show the headings of each side we could say.

2) for i in range(1,200,2): - Is a for loop making i each number from 1 to 200 moving in steps of +2 everytime because the for loop has an order of (start, stop, step)

3) Can be replaced with - print(i, i*2.2) or can be print(f"{i}KG   {i*2.2}LBS")

4) I think {:<9d} {:6.1f} are used for decimal points and significant figures, an easier way would be using the round() method by doing:

```
    print("Kilograms pounds")
    for i in range(1,200,2):
        print(f"{round(i,2)}KG   {round(i*2.2,2)}LBS")
```

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Thanks, Abdullahar

Comment: Hello, Abdulllahar. Can you please help me to solve this. (Display the ASCII character table) Write a program that displays the charactersin the ASCII character table from !to ~. Display ten characters per line. The char-acters are separated by exactly one space.